# How can I load and compile an AngularJs HTML fragment/partial in a Jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I know you can load, compile and test an Angular directive something like so:

```
it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function () {

    var element = $compile("<my-directive></my-directive>")($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(element).toContain("some HTML...");
});
```

Is there a way to do exactly the same but loading and compiling an HTML fragment (from a file) instead of having to create a directive? The fragment is just an ngRepeat and an ngController - wrapping this into a directive is just an added layer of unnecessary complexity, but I'd still like to be able to test the generated HTML.

For example, for an HTML partial `my-table.html':

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped" data-ng-controller="MyController">
 <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in myItems">
...
```

I'd have a Jasmine test that looked something like:

```
it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function () {

    var element = $compile("my-table.html")($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(element).toContain("some HTML...");
});
```

Comment: You can try with the stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026596/accessing-compiled-template-in-unit-tests

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should test only the template of directive, because directive is what is used in your code, not template by itself.

However, I imagine you should do `$http.get('my-table.html')`, get the contents into variable and compile that.

Edit:

Here is some code:

```
var template;

beforeEach(inject(function($http, $httpBackend){
    $http.get('my-table.html').then(function(data) {
        template = data;
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();
}));

it('Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function () {

    var element = $compile(template)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();

    expect(element).toContain("some HTML...");
});
```

This is just an idea how it should work. Not sure if this actually works - haven't tested it, but this is how I would do it if I would need that.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but if all you have is a controller and a repeater, why bother wrapping that up into a directive? It just doesn't add any value - I just want to ensure the HTML generated in my partial is OK - does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by `$http.get` - is this an angular service? Can you give me a code example? thanks